# Не пропускает playMarket версию для планшета

Tags: android, оптимизация, дизайн

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему PlayMarket не пропускает версию для планшетов, пишет оптимизируйте под экраны 10 планшета.

**Файл экрана**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/background">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_fragment"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:name="com.dpmebel.ru.FragmentMenu2"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/header_object"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="2069dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/screen_terminology_ScrollView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/screen_terminology_textView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:text="@string/phone_skype"
            android:id="@+id/screen_terminology_button_call_skype"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/screen_terminology_ScrollView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_terminology_button_call"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:text="@string/phone_tel"
            android:id="@+id/screen_terminology_button_call"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/screen_terminology_imageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/screen_terminology_ScrollView1"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Файл class**

```
public class ScreenTerminologySelected extends Activity implements FragmentMenu.onSomeEventListener {

    final String toLogs = "ScreenTerminologySelected";
    FragmentMenu frag2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_terminology);
        if ( API.isPhone(getApplicationContext())) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
         textView.setText(request);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                if ( API.isPhone(getApplicationContext())) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Log.e(toLogs,"fr = " + frag2);
                    if (frag2 == null) {
                        frag2 = new FragmentMenu();
                        ft.add(R.id.screen_terminology_frameLayout, frag2);
                    } else {
                        ft.remove(frag2);
                        frag2 = null;
                    }
                    ft.commit();
                }
                Log.e(toLogs,"press HOME");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void someEvent(int s) {
        //обработка
    }

}
```

**Файл манифест**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.dpmebel.ru"
          android:versionCode="11"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Required to download files from Google Play -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Required to keep CPU alive while downloading files (NOT to keep screen awake) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Required to poll the state of the network connection and respond to changes -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Required to check whether Wi-Fi is enabled -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <!-- Required to read and write the expansion files on shared storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk   android:minSdkVersion="11"
                android:targetSdkVersion="14"
                />
    <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:logo="@drawable/icon">
        <activity

                android:name="MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenAbout_Company"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenCatalog"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenContact"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenNews">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenOneNew"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenSelect_divan"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenSelected"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenTerminology"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenWhere_buy"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenSelect_divan_article"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenTerminologySelected"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenWebView"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                   />
        <activity android:name=".ScreenFirstCatalog"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenFavorites"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Покажите манифест - настройка на разные экраны зависит от манифеста

Comment: добавил,посмотрите еще раз,пожалуйств

Comment: С чего вы взяли что не пропускает? Добавьте скриншотов для планшетов и все ок должно быть.

Comment: пишет 
Оптимизируйте свое приложение для планшетных ПК
Дизайн страниц должен предусматривать максимальное использование пространства на экране 10-дюймового планшетного ПК